# Issue initializing mocks in a view model in testing classes - swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing, mocking, initialization

I'm trying to set up a view model for testing with a variety of mock repositories, and having issues loading the mocks in my test class - I've created an initializer in my main view model that should include the three repositories, and set them to the actual repositories if nothing is selected, but allow me to select a different mock that conforms to each repository protocol in my testing class.

The issue I'm running into when I load my testing class, it says the variables for two of my repositories are not in scope. Any idea what may cause this kind of error?

```
class SeasonGoalsViewModel {
    @Published var goalRepository: GoalStoreType
    @Published var seasonRepository: SeasonStoreType?
    @Published var seasonLength: SeasonLength?
    
    var userProfile: UserProfile
    
    init(goalRepository: GoalStoreType = GoalRepository(), seasonRepository: SeasonStoreType? = SeasonRepository(), userProfile: UserProfile? = CurrentUserProfile.shared.currentUser) {
        self.goalRepository = goalRepository
        self.seasonRepository = seasonRepository
        self.userProfile = userProfile!
    }
}
```

```
import XCTest
@testable import MyApp

class SeasonGoalsViewModelTests: XCTestCase {
    
    var sut: SeasonGoalsViewModel!
    
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        sut = SeasonGoalsViewModel(goalRepository: MockGoalsRepository(), seasonRepository = MockSeasonRepository(), userProfile = TestUserProfile.shared.userProfile)
    }
```

I'm getting errors on the seasonRepository, saying "Cannot find 'seasonRepository' in scope, and on the userProfile, says "Cannot find 'userProfile' in scope".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `=` with `:` in ***setUp()*** while creating `sut` object.

```
import XCTest
    @testable import MyApp
    
    class SeasonGoalsViewModelTests: XCTestCase {
        
        var sut: SeasonGoalsViewModel!
        
        override func setUp() {
            super.setUp()
            sut = SeasonGoalsViewModel(goalRepository: MockGoalsRepository(), seasonRepository: MockSeasonRepository(), userProfile: TestUserProfile.shared.userProfile)
        }
```

Comment: Oh my gosh. *facepalm* Thank you.